# Questions about Xournal

Tags: pdf

When open a pdf file in Xournal, how can I

- select original text
- show the bookmarks (i.e.outlines) on a separate panel?
- search in the original text and the added annotated text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> To use Xournal to highlight or add text to a PDF file, select File >
>   Annotate PDF (you can also chose the usual File > Open, but make sure
>   you then select to view all files, not just Xournal files) and select
>   the PDF you want to annotate or highlight text.
>
> Xournal cannot save a file in PDF format but you can easily select
>   File > Export to PDF to achieve something similar so it's a viable
>   solution for those who are looking for a reliable tool to
>   annotate/highlight text in PDF files on Linux.

Source: [HIGHLIGHT TEXT OR ANNOTATE PDF FILES IN UBUNTU WITH XOURNAL](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/highlight-text-or-annotate-pdf-files-in.html).

Comment: Thanks! (1) When I export to PDF, the resulting pdf file is 10 times larger in storage size. How can I make it only slighly bigger than the original pdf file? (2)is there any way to search for a word in Xournal? (the word can appear either in the original pdf file, or in the connotations I added later)